# Is it possible to query for place details with a list of place ids

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I know I can query for place details using a place id, but how do I query using a list of place ids? I'd prefer to do this in one call if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no bulk lookup method in the iOS Places API.  There's just the `lookUpPlaceID` method, but you can call it concurrently just fine to lookup several places in parallel.